# Remove child from Batch node one after another with a pause

Tags: cocos2d-x, frame-rate

I am trying to remove a set of children from the batch node one by one after some pause . So if three children are there, then firstly parent will disappear immidiatley , then after 1 second first child will disappear, then after another 1 second(total 2 seconds) 2nd child will disappear and after another 1 second(total 3 seconds) third child will disappear.

Right now I am removing them from the batchnode like :-

```
batchNode->removeChild(child1,true);
sleep(1);
batchNode->removeChild(child2,true);
sleep(2)
batchNode->removeChild(child3,true);
```

But they all disappear from screen at same time ! although pause is there. Is it because they all are part of same batchNode so any action taken on children will be applied at one go. ?

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it , I used two different ways as described:-

**1> By postponing the removal of subsequent children in further frames.**

**2> or instead of depending on the frames, I used delta time (time since the last frame was drawn).So remove a child only after say 0.5 secs.**

Using either of the above way , I can omit the use of sleep which can hog my main thread.

Here are the details, considering I have in total three children to remove:-

**1> By postponing the removal of subsequent children in further frames.**

In the current frame I will remove first child then will set a flag to notify in the Update not to do anything but wait for say 15 frames, while waiting 15 frames I can do other tasks also which doesnot have impact on gameplay

Although with this I have flexibility to wait for any number of frames, but I will have to regulate the frame rate for different devices, as in slow devices, waiting 15 frames can take more time  than fast device, and I am not able to know if cocos2dx does regulate the frame rate itself, so I quickly jumped to next solution.

**2> or instead of depending on the frames, I used delta time (time since the last frame was drawn).So remove a child only after say 0.5 secs.**

Here instead of waiting 15 frames I used following condition inside Update(float dt):-

```
if(gameState==WaitForNextChildRemoval)
{
deltaTime=deltaTime+dt;

if(deltaTime>=0.5)
{
releaseNextChild();
deltaTime=0;
}
}
```

here irrespective of the device(slow or fast), next child will be removed after 0.5 secs.
One improvement I think should be made is when deltaTime becomes more than say 1 sec , and then instead of removing only next one child, it should remove two children (0.5 secs for each) at one go , as player is expecting to remove one child after 0.5 secs so deltaTime  being 1 sec(approx), I should balance this expectation.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

ie, they all disappear together after 3 seconds ? Basically, i think that the sleep is actually blocking the main thread, so the update & draw cycle will only resume after the last one of your statements.

I would do something like that by running some kind of CCSequence , with delay actions and callBlock actions to cascade properly. This is all executed within the main thread, so the display will be refreshed during the cascade.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Run a CCSequence with a CCDelay and CCCallBlock for each child

Comment: we don't have CCCallBlock in Cocos2dx,so I tried CCCallFunc,parent disappear quickly and after a delay other two children disappear together.I used this in loop 3 times(total shapes removed)this->runAction(CCSequence::create(delayAction,CCCallFunc::create(this,callfunc_selector(GameLayer::releaseChildCallFunc)),NULL)),"this" is GameLayer so i tried other approach. Now I remove parent quickly, then its children after 10 frames, and other children after another 10 frames. While I am waiting I am doing no work in game. If frame rate is regulated then it should work fine , pls share your thoughts.

Comment: Bivis can you please elaborate on what YvesLeBorg is trying to achieve by CCSequence? I tried but i could not achive it, please read above comment for details.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep() argument is typically measured in milliseconds, so try sleep(1000); in second and fourth lines.
Also, maybe, you'd better to use Actions (CCSequence stuffed with CCDelay and CCCallFunc) instead of sleep() which blocks all your game.

Comment: yes you are right Sleep will block my main thread, please read comment in above answer,to know the way I am doing it now. Please share your thoughts on this..Thanks